# I got null value when i map one to many mapping using list in hibernate

Tags: java, database, hibernate, struts, dto

I am work on struts2 and hibernate . i having a problem when i implement one to many mapping in my program . I got the null value of list from jsp . Please help me there is code :

parent pojo class is :`

```
 private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
 private int id;
 private String voucherno;
 private String  vendor_name;
 private String  address;
 private Integer vendor_invoice_no;
 private Date    invoice_date;
 private Date    due_date;
 private Date    user_date;
 private String  currency;
 private Double  exRate;
 private Double  totalAmt;
 private Double totalSTex;
 private Double tds_amount;
 private Double s_tax_amount;
 private String tds_section;
 private Double tds_cost;
 private Double tdsamount;
 private Double  payable_amount;
 private String  narration;
 private List<Payable_datail> recievable_detail  ;
```

child pojo class is :

```
private Integer payable_Id;
private String chargeHead; 
private String description; 
private Double amount; 
private Double tamount; 
private String st_chargehead;
private String s_tax_list;
private String service_tax_category;
private Double s_tax;
private Double edu_case;
private Double high_case;
private Double total_s_tax;
private Payable_detaildto payable_detailDto;
```

Parent hbm file is :

```
 <list name="recievable_detail" inverse="false" lazy="true" cascade="all">  
      <key column="ID" ></key>  
      <index column="index"></index>  
      <one-to-many class="com.envosys.dto.Payable_datail"/>  
      </list>
```

Child hbm file is :

```
<many-to-one name="payable_detailDto" class="com.envosys.dto.Payable_detaildto" fetch="join" unique="false" update="true" insert="true" optimistic-lock="true" not-found="exception" embed-xml="true">
             <column name="ID" /> 
       </many-to-one>
```

and jsp is where i am using this list " recievable_detail " : is

```
  cell0.innerHTML = "<td align='left'><input  id='chargeHead"+count+"' name='recievable_detail["+count+"].chargeHead' type='text' value='"+chargehead+"' class='text ui-widget-content ui-corner-all chargeHead' size=50 ' onblur=\"check("+count+")\" ><input type =\"hidden\" id='set_service"+count+"' name = \"set_service\"> ";
  cell1.innerHTML = "<td align='left'><textarea  id='description"+count+"' name='recievable_detail["+count+"].description' type='textarea' rows=\"1\" cols=\"30\" class='text ui-widget-content ui-corner-all'> ";
  cell2.innerHTML = "<td align='left'><input  id='amount"+count+"' name='recievable_detail["+count+"].amount' type='text' value="+amount+" class='text ui-widget-content ui-corner-all'  onkeyup='data1()'> ";
  cell3.innerHTML = "<td align='left'><input id='tamount"+count+"' name='recievable_detail["+count+"].tamount' type='text' value="+tamount+" class='text ui-widget-content ui-corner-all'> ";
  cell4.innerHTML = "<a onclick=\"removeRow("+count+")\" align=\"center\"><img src=\"images/Minus.png\"/></a></td>";
```

my problem is that i unable to map between child class and parent class because i got value of list "recievable_detail" is null in getter and setter of parent class  . please help me and give me any idea and suitable suggestion to me.

```
    `
```

Answer (score 0):

All collection properties must be initialized with an empty collection of proper type; in your case

`private List<Payable_datail> recievable_detail = new ArrayList<Payable_datail> ;`